# Use touch event for custom view without interfering with the user's touch event

Tags: android, android-custom-view, touch-event, ontouchlistener, custom-view

I create a library for a custom view. I use `OnTouchListener()` to handle custom touch events, but I want the user to be able to set their own `OnTouchListener()`. How can I handle it?!

Comment: Don't set an `OnTouchListener` on your custom `View`. Instead, override its `onTouchEvent()` method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should override onTouchEvent() for custom views

```java
@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    Toast.makeText(this.getContext(), "Touched layout", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    Log.d("TOUCH", "Touched layout");

    return super.onTouchEvent(event);
}
```

According to official docs

> onTouch() - This returns a boolean to indicate whether your listener consumes this event. The important thing is that this event can have multiple actions that follow each other. So, if you return false when the down action event is received, you indicate that you have not consumed the event and are also not interested in subsequent actions from this event. Thus, you will not be called for any other actions within the event, such as a finger gesture, or the eventual up action event.

Comment: Nice to hear that